# Request replacement DEFERED mode is not working for Google Play billing Upgrade/Downgrade

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I am using below replacement mode for upgrading subscription

```
val subscriptionUpdateParamsBuilder = SubscriptionUpdateParams.newBuilder()
subscriptionUpdateParamsBuilder.setSubscriptionReplacementMode(BillingFlowParams.SubscriptionUpdateParams.ReplacementMode.DEFERRED)
```

[image]

It should successfully open  upgrade pop with provided replacement mode.